# How to automatically log out an user in kde?

Tags: arch-linux, kde5

There are two users in my pc being me (user1) the one with sudo privileges.
I want that at 12:00 user2 logs out from his kde session in such a way that he cant prevent it and that all application are there when he log in later.

I tried using cron, as user2, me and root, like this

```
00 12 * * * qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

Also i tried cron as root, like this

```
00 12 * * * user2 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

Both of them didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `DISPLAY` variable as `cron` runs independently from the GUI.

```
 00 12 * * * user2 DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

Comment: Didnt work, i tried ```sudo crontab -u user2 -e```  with ```00 12 * * * DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0```and ```sudo nvim /etc/crontab``` with ```00 12 * * * user2 DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0```

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` return for you? Also: better use the full path of the `qdbus` command. I strongly assume it might not be in the PATH that cron uses. What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

@FelixJN Ok somehow i manage to lost both the password and mail from @224843 account, i will continue with this one.
`echo $DISPLAY` gives me `:0`, adding the full path to qbus didnt solve it, but searching in `journalctl` i find:

```
CROND[2332]: (user2) CMD (DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0)
CROND[2331]: (user2) CMDOUT (Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead)
CROND[2331]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user user2
```

This only happens when i use `sudo crontab -u user2 -e` if i use `/etc/crontab` nothing appears in the logs

PS:

```
sudo crontab -u user2 -l
00 12 * * * DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

```
cat /etc/crontab
00 12 * * * user2 DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0
```

Comment: Since it sounds like you've lost access to your original account, please visit https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact to request that the profiles be merged, so that you can take ownership of your question and apply subsequent updates. Thank you!